# How to open mat-expansion-panel when the form group of that panel is invalid?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend, angular8

I have a `formArray` with multiple `formGroups`. Each of the `formGroup` is inside an expansion panel. Now when I click on `"Check what's missing"` button, form validation runs and shows errors for the form fields that are invalid. But if the mat-expansion-panel is closed, you can't see which fields are invalid. When I check for form validation, I want the expansion panels with invalid `formGroup` to open so that the user can see which form fields are invalid. I have added the code for your reference:

```
<!-- Personal Form inside Expansion Panel Personal -->
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            Personal
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <app-personal-form [form]="form"></app-personal-form>
</mat-expansion-panel>

<!-- Work Form inside Expansion Panel Work -->
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            Work
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <app-work-form [form]="form"></app-work-form>
</mat-expansion-panel>

<!-- Address Form inside Expansion Panel Work -->
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            Address
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <app-address-form [form]="form"></app-address-form>
</mat-expansion-panel>

<div class="top-15" align="end">
    <button class="btn-success" mat-raised-button [disabled]="form.valid" (click)="form.showErrors()">Check what's missing</button> 
    <button class="btn-success" mat-raised-button [disabled]="!form.valid || !form.dirty" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi show your ts code as well

Comment: please shows us ts code of above template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the expansions pannels using ViewChildren

```
  import {MatExpansionPanel} from '@angular/material/expansion';

  @ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel) pannels:QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>
```

In a submit you can make some like, remember that the pannels will be with index 0 for the "Personal", 1 for the "Work"....

```
submit()
{
  this.pannels.forEach((x,index)=>{
     if (index==0 && this.form.get('Personal').invalid)
        x.open();
     if (index==1 && this.form.get('Work').invalid)
        x.open();
   ....
   })
}
```

NOTE: I don't know about how you make your form, so the condition can change, but I hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

Please see if this helps you:

```
import { Component, Input,ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  myForm: FormGroup
  expanded = []
  errorPanles = []
  formSubmitted = false
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private appRef: ApplicationRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      personal: this.fb.group({
        fname: ['', [Validators.required]],
        lname: ['']
      }),
      work: this.fb.group({
        designation: ['', [Validators.required]],
        department: ['', [Validators.required]],
      })
    });
  }

  send(form) {
    this.formSubmitted = true
    this.expanded = []
    this.errorPanles = []
    this.appRef.tick();
    for (var key in form.controls) {
      if (form.controls[key].valid === false) {
        this.expanded.push(key)
      }
    }      
    this.errorPanles = this.expanded  
    if(this.errorPanles.length>0){
      // Form will not submit and material panel with error will open
    }else{
      // do whatever you want in case no error
    }
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s59zmn

I am also learning phase in Angular.

Comment: Hi there. Answers in form of "this code will help" can be improved a great deal by explaining _why_ the code might help. In general, answers that offer explanation and detail will be useful for a wider range of future readers.